# Django: Load production settings for celery

Tags: django, celery

My Django project has multiple settings file for development, production and testing. And I am using supervisor to manage the celery worker. My question how to load the settings file for celery based on the environment I am in.

Answer (score 3):

By using environment variables. Let's say you have the following setting files at the root of your repository.

- `config.settings.development.py`
- `config.settings.production.py`
- ...

[The recommended way](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to have your celery instance defined is in your config like `celery.py` module:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
# os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.production')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Instead of setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable within the module (I have commented that out) make sure that those are present in the environment at the time that `supervisord` is started.

To set those variables in your staging, testing, and production system you can execute the following bash command.

E.g. on your production system:

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

I would also suggest you load them from an `.env` file. In my opinion thats more convenient. You could do that with for example [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

---

**Update**

The `.env` file is mostly unique on your different systems and is usually not under source/version control. By unique I mean for development you may have a more verbose `LOG_LEVEL` or a different `SECRET_KEY`, because you don't want them to show up in your source control or want to be able to adjust them without modifying your source files.

So, in your `base.py` (`production.py` and `development.py` are inheriting) you can load the variables from the file with for example:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()  # .env file has to be in the same directory

# ...
import os
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = os.getenv("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")
print(DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)
# ...
```

I personally don't use the package since I use `docker`, which has a declarative way of defining an `.env` file but the code above should give you an idea how it could work. There are similar packages out there like [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) which is featured in the book [Two Scoops of Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981467342). So I would tend to use this instead of `python-dotenv`, a matter of taste.

Comment: If the server restarts for some reason then I don't think it will work. Can me pls shed some light on `.env` file technique?

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to configure different settings files. From here you have two options. You can use the django-admin settings param at runtime

```
django-admin runserver --settings=thecelery.settings
```

Also, you may have the option to configure settings in the settings.py. If you have a 1 settings file currently, this would require you to setup additional settings files, and set environment variables on the instance. Then in your base settings file, you can do soemthing like this

```
import os

environment your_env = os.environ["environment"]
if your_env == "celery":
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "thecelerysettings")
else:
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "defaultsettings")
```